# Dynamic LINQ query based on values from object

Tags: c#, linq

im trying to implement  the filtering logic and I want to create a dynamic LINQ query based on an data object I'll be sending to the backend

so basically this:

```
[
   {
    "key": "string",
    "comparisonOperators": "equal",
    "value": "string"
   },
   {
     "key": "string",
     "comparisonOperators": "greater than",
     "value": "string"
   },
   {
     "key": "string",
     "comparisonOperators": "less than",
     "value": "string"
   }
]
```

should be automatically translated to a LINQ expression equal to `select * from x where key = vale and key > value and key < value;`

Currently I wrote the below code which obviously is wrong

```
        var queryString = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE ";
        var filterArray = FilterJson.ToArray();
        string comparisonOperator;
        for (var v = 0; v < filterArray.Length; v++)
        {
            switch (filterArray[v].ComparisonOperators)
            {
                case "equals":
                    comparisonOperator = "=";
                    break;
                case "greater than":
                    comparisonOperator = ">";
                    break;
                case "less than":
                    comparisonOperator = "<";
                    break;
                default:
                    comparisonOperator = "=";
                    break;
            }
            queryString += filterArray[v].Key + filterArray + filterArray[v].Value;
            if (v + 1 != filterArray.Length)
            {
                queryString += " AND ";
            }
        }
```

The Object can be infinite. Is there anyway to do it in C# dynamically (and if so can you provide any guidelines) or shall I just stick on the way I already implemented?

*My main issue is how to dynamically set the comparison operator in the LINQ statement.*

Comment: [Expression Trees](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/expression-trees/) can accomplish the goal but learning curve is quite steep.

Comment: The condition `key = value and key > value and key < value` is always false because the key cannot be equal, smaller than and greater than at the same time! Note: replacing the ANDs with ORs would make the condition always true (except for NULL values). So, this SQL select command makes no sense. Maybe you meant using a CASE statement?

Comment: For the input side, it looks like you're trying to reinvent either OData or GraphQL, either of which might be worth considering instead (notwithstanding that they may not cover all your use cases). For the SQL side, you're probably looking at a more basic ORM layer like Dapper, rather than LINQ; LINQ doesn't give you much here besides added complexity, if you're going to be building most of the query dynamically anyway.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes that was just for an example...

Comment: @JeroenMostert No, it is not like that. What I am trying to do is a filtering system for my frontend. basically i will have a table where the user will be able to filter data per column (can filter using more than one column as well) so I need a dynamic call to the database for retrieving the data

Comment: If you're not already tied to EF and are OK with building SQL, be sure to give [this article](https://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search.html) a read. Fully dynamic SQL isn't always needed, and even where it is there are some traps and pitfalls to keep in mind.

Comment: You can you use Linq dynamicly like this :

Items.Where("Id = 123 And Age > 18");

Comment: Consider using [DynamicLINQ](https://github.com/StefH/System.Linq.Dynamic.Core) if you don't mind giving up type safety and possibly having runtime errors.

Comment: @Bouam my main issue is the comparison operator, how can I dynamically add it into the code?

Comment: @JeroenMostert unfortunately I must use EF... my main issue is how to set the comparison operator  dynamically in the statement

Comment: Please replace this row : 
queryString += filterArray[v].Key + " " + comparisonOperator  + " " + filterArray[v].Value

And later you can use : 

Items.Where(queryString); // In linq you dont need to use select from ... that's more sql statement

Comment: @Bouam can you give me an example on what the ````queryString``` will be? i didn't quite get your suggestion